# How to avoid div overlapping when embiding a youtube video on a webpage?

Tags: html, css

using the two methods to embed videos from youtube, the iframe:

```
<iframe width="400" height="300" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/2D_AU8-2QWY?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

and the old one:

```
<object width="400" height="300"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/RNclwz9B_GQ?version=3&amp;hl=it_IT&amp;rel=0"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/RNclwz9B_GQ?version=3&amp;hl=it_IT&amp;rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="400" height="300" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>
```

Im always gettin an ugly overlapping effect on my divs, like this:

[image]

So the question is how to avoid that? Thanks!

Comment: did you want to just put it behind the log in or fix it to 1 spot on the page?

Comment: it has to be behind everything

Comment: Does it happen in all browsers or specific browsers?

Answer (score 1):

Try `z-index` in css to order your div's this way you can pick what go's on top

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/z-index

Comment: Seems like z-index has nothing to do with the problem. Notice the third screenshot. Overlays widgets normally have a very high z-index.

Answer (score 1):

To add on 1ftw1's answer; to allow setting `z-index` on flash content you need to include the `wmode` param

From [Adobe's site](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html):

`wmode` - Possible values: window, direct, opaque, transparent, gpu. Sets the Window Mode property of the Flash movie for transparency, layering, positioning, and rendering in the browser. If this attribute is omitted, the default value is "window". For more information, see Using Window Mode (wmode) values below.
**window** - The SWF content plays in its own rectangle ("window") on a web page. The browser will determinehow the SWF content is layered against other HTML elements. With this value, you cannot explicitly specify if SWF content will appear above or below other HTML elements on the page.
**direct** - Use direct to path rendering. This bypasses compositing in the screen buffer and renders the SWF content directly to the screen. This wmode value is recommended to provide the best performance for content playback and enables hardware accelerated presentation of SWF content that uses Stage Video or Stage 3D.
**opaque** - The SWF content is layered together with other HTML elements on the page. The SWF is opaque and will hide everything layered behind it on the page. This option will reduce playback perfomance compared to wmode=window or wmode=direct.
**transparent** - The SWF content is layered together with other HTML elements on the page. The SWF background color (Stage color) is transparent, and HTML elements beneath the SWF will be visible through any transparent areas of the SWF, with alpha blending. This option will reduce playback performance compared to wmode=window or wmode=direct.
**gpu** - Use additional hardware acceleration on some internet connected TVs and mobile devices. In contrast to other wmode values, pixel fidelity for display list graphics is not guaranteed. Otherwise, this value is similar to wmode=direct.